# How to create curved edges (something I thought was impossible) like this internet example?

Tags: edges

I have always believed that edges are always straight in Blender, that that is just how it works.  then I ran across topologyguides.com.

Their tutorials are terse, but take a look at this one and in each picture the final step has curved edges.

https://topologyguides.com/bevel-width-transitions

I don't know if they are using an add-in, or what.  I haven't been able to find an answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like they aren't using actually curved edges (as far as I know, you're right that would be impossible) but rather they're using a Subdivision Surface modifier with the "On Cage" option turned on (you can see it at the top of the modifier, next to the options toggling using the modifier during render, in the viewport, and in Edit mode). If you don't see that option, it may be because the subdivision modifier isn't first (the option disappears if there's another modifier before it).

As I understand it, the "On Cage" option just projects the edges onto the surface produced by applying the modifier, which makes them look curved. It's just an aesthetic thing, though - internally, the edges are still straight.

Comment: Yep, I was unaware of this visualization.  There must be a way to hide edge creases because the model is not subdivided throughout, yet none of the edges are highlighted pink.  I'm assuming I'm just not aware of the option to hide the highlighting indicated creases and whatnot.